# Making the user scroll all the XtraGridControl o a GridControl

Tags: c#, scroll, scrollbar

I've got a XtraGridControl in a winform, I need to add a validation method that should ensure that the user has at least seen or navigated all the data inside the XtraGrid and then present an option for saving the data.

I need to know if the user has scroll all the way of the vertical axis inside the XTraGridControl, and then show the user an option for saving the data.

I've seen this behavior in some installers where you should scroll all the way of the text of the contract before the button "Next" is enabled. As I said before I need to do this not in a RichTExtBox but in the XtragridControl.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
void Main()
{
    new MyForm().Show();
}

public class MyForm : Form
{
    public MyForm()
    {
        var grid = new GridControl();
        var gridview = new DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView(grid);
        var button = new Button { Enabled = false, Text = "Next", Dock= DockStyle.Bottom };

        gridview.TopRowChanged += (o, e) => 
        {
            int bottomRowIndex = gridview.TopRowIndex + ((GridViewInfo)gridview.GetViewInfo()).RowsInfo.Count;
            if (bottomRowIndex == gridview.RowCount)
            {
                button.Enabled = true;
            }
        };

        grid.MainView = gridview;
        grid.DataSource = new [] {9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1};

        Controls.Add(grid);
        Controls.Add(button);
    }
}
```